# RewriteRule negation failing

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to do the following redirect:

any url such as:

```
/about/apple/1
/about/green
/about/apples
/about/pears/1
```

to:

```
/about/apple
```

using the following, which does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^about/(!apple) /about/apple [R=301,L]
```

The following test line works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^about/apples /about/apple [R=301,L]
```

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^about/!(apple) /about/apple [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about/(?!apple) /about/apple [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(about/apple)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} about(.*)
RewriteRule . /about/apple [R=301,L]
```

And also tried putting it into a rewritecond before hand, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression pattern `^about/(?!apples)`  matches none of the uris you want to redirect.  It matches `/about/foobar` but does not match `/about/apples` or `/about/apples/foobar` as you have negated the `apples` substring in the pattern.

You can use

```
RewriteRule ^about/apples/(.*)$  /about/$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect `/about/apples/` or `/about/apples/foobar` to `/about/foobar` .

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Hi there - I think you misunderstood the request. I'm trying to redirect everything under /about/* to /about/apple. So I could use something like:

`RewriteRule ^about/(.*)$  /about/apple [L,R]`

but this would also create a redirect loop for /about/apple

Comment: @cirrus123 Sorry my mistake. I should have read your question carefully. You can use 

`RewriteRule ^about/((?!apple).+)$ /about/apple [L,R]` to redirect everything after `/about/apple` to `/apple` .

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the updated code. It works better now except if 'apple' is in the URL, such as '/about/apples' or '/about/apple/1' it does not redirect. However '/about/banana' does seem to work.

Comment: @cirrus123 so you want to redirect `/about/apples` to `/about/apples` ?

Comment: No - as stated: /about/ANYTHING to /about/apple

Comment: @cirrus123 

Try this :


`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about/apples/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^about/(.*)$ /about/apples [L,R]` The rewrite Condition above excludes the destination path and avoids Infinite redirect loop error.